# Experimental Decorators Support in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting the following error in VSCODE:

[image]

How this is "easily" solvable by creating a jsconfig.json file in the root of your project etc etc. I'm saying "easily" because even doing that didn't solve my problem.

Isn't there a way to set this in my settings? Instead of having to go and create this file in the root of each of my projects just for the sake of hiding this warning? Surely?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using `jsconfig.json` is sadly the only way to disable the warning message